# How do you refer to an Ember.js object inside a nested object definition?

Tags: ember.js

I am working on Ember.js classes to help with working with forms. In the snippet below, my definition of `widget` needs to bind to its `value` to a property of the object in which it is nested hence I set the binding to `'App.AjaxForm.aField.value'`.

Is there a less repetitive way to say this?

```
App.Field = Ember.Object.extend({
    // The Ember.js equivalent of ``django.forms.fields.Field``.
    value: null,
    errors: [],
    widget: null
});

App.AjaxForm = App.Form.create({
    action: '/ajax/',
    fields: [
        'aField'
    ],
    aField: App.Field.create({
        widget: Ember.TextField.extend({
            valueBinding: 'App.AjaxForm.aField.value'
        })
    })
});
```

UPDATE: Added `App.Field` definition.

Comment: This question is a bit confusing (at least to me). Are you wanting something like valueBinding: 'parentView.value'. Without knowing how you've implemented App.Field it will be hard to give a complete answer.

Comment: @CoryLoken I suppose 'parentView.value' is similar to what I want. I updated the question with the definition of `App.Field`. It is just an Ember object with a few properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my solution.

```
App.Field = Ember.Object.extend({
    // The Ember.js equivalent of ``django.forms.fields.Field``.
    value: null,
    errors: [],
    widget_class: Ember.TextField,
    widget: function () {
        return this.get('widget_class').extend({
            field: this,
            valueBinding: 'field.value'
        });
    }.property()
});
```